# `input`'s position in a table

Tags: html, css

Can someone explains how is that possible that an `input`of type "submit" is placed at the top-left although it's inside the third `<tr>`
I can change its position to the right place through `margin` and `position` properties, but there should be no need for them at all in this case.
see the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Home</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div style="border:2px solid black;margin-top:10%;">
                <div class="row">
                    <table style="margin-left:10%;width:85%;" class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>album name</th>
                                <th>Number of images</th>
                                <th>Order</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input placeholder="album's name" name="album_name">
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <input placeholder="#of images eg.8" id="no_of_images" name="NoOfImages">
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <input placeholder="order between other albums eg. 1" name="album_order">
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <input  style="" class="btn btn-info btn-md" value="Submit" name="submit">

                        </tr>
                    </table>

                    <table style="margin-top:10%;" id="images_table" class="table table-hover">
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The only valid children of a tr are th and td - your input needs a valid container.

Comment: Oh thanks mate. That's right, forgot the `<td>` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Insert `td` like this:*

```
<td> <---------------
     <input  style="" class="btn btn-info btn-md" value="Submit" name="submit">
</td> <--------------
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div style="border:2px solid black;margin-top:10%;">
        <div class="row">
            <table style="margin-left:10%;width:85%;" class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                       <th>album name</th>
                       <th>Number of images</th>
                       <th>Order</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                           <input placeholder="album's name" name="album_name">
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <input placeholder="#of images eg.8" id="no_of_images" name="NoOfImages">
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <input placeholder="order between other albums eg. 1" name="album_order">
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input  style="" class="btn btn-info btn-md" value="Submit" name="submit">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
            <table style="margin-top:10%;" id="images_table" class="table table-hover">
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ya its working now after adding the '<td>' tag thanks for your effort :)

Comment: It will be available after 2 minutes. I will

Comment: Wish you too :)

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add td in your tr section, and because your third tr has only one td, you must set colspan to 3 as it's property...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Home</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div style="border:2px solid black;margin-top:10%;">
                <div class="row">
                    <table style="margin-left:10%;width:85%;" class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>album name</th>
                                <th>Number of images</th>
                                <th>Order</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input placeholder="album's name" name="album_name">
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <input placeholder="#of images eg.8" id="no_of_images" name="NoOfImages">
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <input placeholder="order between other albums eg. 1" name="album_order">
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3">
                                <input  style="" class="btn btn-info btn-md" value="Submit" name="submit">
                            </td>


                        </tr>
                    </table>

                    <table style="margin-top:10%;" id="images_table" class="table table-hover">
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's right. Thanks for the information about that `colspan` that would be useful.